# How can I change the background of MUI's menus?

Tags: material-ui

Some of the solutions I found online are not working for me, I managed to changed the colour of the buttons on the menu, but the menu itself is still white?

This is my code:

```
<Menu
    open={open}
    onClose={(e) => setOpen(false)}
  
  >

  <MenuList
    sx={{backgroundColor:"red"}}
    id="demo-positioned-menu"
    aria-labelledby="demo-positioned-button"
    // open={open}
    onClose={(e) => setOpen(false)}
    anchorOrigin={{
      vertical: "top",
      horizontal: "left",
    }}
    transformOrigin={{
      vertical: "top",
      horizontal: "left",
    }}
  >
    <MenuItem>Profile</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>My account</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>Logout</MenuItem>
  </MenuList>
  </Menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a prop `MenuListProps` on the `Menu` component you can pass your backgroundColor in there and it will apply to all the styles of the Menu.

```js
    <Menu
      open={open}
      onClose={(e) => setOpen(false)}
      MenuListProps={{
        sx: {
          backgroundColor: "red",
        },
      }}
    >
```